# grab session value from remote server

Tags: php, session

i got a problem which is i want to get value of a $_SESSION[rp_djname]; to a remote server but the problem whenever i echo it and try to get it through file_get_content() it dont show although it does when i access the php file that i did to echo $_SESSION[rp_djname]; value to be grabed on main server to be grabbed from. here is the code

```
<?php
session_start();
$dj_name_session = $_SESSION[rp_djname];
print_r($dj_name_session);
$sam = '1234';
echo $sam;
?>
```

found that 1234 show in remote server but not session value.

here how i grab the echo code (on remote server)

```
$f="url/filename.php";
$data = file_get_contents($f);
echo $data;
```

any idea how to achieve that? been trying since early morning with heavy search but no use :(

Thanks in advance

Comment: isn't that : $_SESSION['rp_djname'] ?

Comment: I don't understand how you are expected to grab contents from a remote server when the "URL" you are using is a local file path reference.  Also, unless you have some common shared session backend (i.e. database) between these servers, I don;t see how you are expecting to share session information. Overall you question is not very clear on what you are trying to do.

Comment: i just want to log the djname that is on a certain page in a text file on the remote server thats all @ mike what do u mean by url is local file path reference?

Comment: He means you are not calling a script on a remote server. You are just fetching the contents of the PHP file itself because you do a local file call with file_get_contents when you call $f="url/filename.php";

Comment: guys i got real url and file name in my own version but i did changed them in the post so as not to be posted to public but i got url and filename in my own version

Comment: As faridzs said - you need quotation marks in `$dj_name_session = $_SESSION['rp_djname'];`. As others said - you need `$f = "http://remote_domaina.com/full_path/filename.php";`

Comment: is there any suggestions or ideas to be able to grab the session to remote server

Comment: btw: sometimes `file_get_contents` can't get remote content - it depends on PHP config.

Comment: still dont work, anyways i wil do it in another way as long as it dont work this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call a script on the server hosting the session via Ajax.

This script get the session datas you need locally and you have just to get the datas calling the script via ajax from the distant server.

Comment: Ok it's a problem :) but it's the only good way to do. I use this to get session data for a chrome extension. if u know a little javascript & jquery i can give you my code exemple to adapt...